# LAStools errors in QGIS: 'cannot open lasreaderlas with file name .las', 'could not open lasreader'?

Tags: qgis, installation, error, lidar, lastools

I am experiencing some problems with LAStools. I have two QGIS separate installations: 2.14.17 is a standalone installation and 2.18.11 is a Osgeo4w installation.

I have followed the procedure to use LAStools described [here](https://mappinggis.com/2015/04/como-configurar-lastools-en-qgis/) (in Spanish) and [here](https://rapidlasso.com/2013/09/29/how-to-install-lastools-toolbox-in-qgis/). Each time I want to view a .las file (with `lasview`), the command seems to start but it closes (it happens with other tools as well).

In the log console I have the following message:

> 017-07-27T08:37:10 0   LAStools command line
>               C:\lidtools\bin\lasview -i "C:/Users/Mapoteca2/Desktop/demo/demo.las" -points 5000000
>               LAStools console output
>               ERROR: cannot open file 'demo.las'
>               ERROR: cannot open lasreaderlas with file name 'demo.las'
>               ERROR: could not open lasreader

This is odd since I am able to use the .las file from LAStools GUI. I have declared all LAStools executables as exceptions in my antivirus but the problem persists in both installations. I am running both installations of QGIS in Win10 64 bits with 32gb of ram.

Comment: Why do you have a 'lidtools' folder instead of 'LAStools'? Do you get all the 3 error messages at once? Is it correct the word 'lasreaderlas' in the second error message? The error is probably coming from some misspecification in the program/tools' path.

Comment: I worked with the original folder, the path I am showing was intended to overcome a problem in the original path. So I copied all the lastool files to this new folder. With the original ones it did not work either. as for the lasreaderlas is en exact copy of the log...

Comment: Is it the same thing to set the following part: _"C:/Users/Mapoteca2/Desktop/demo/demo.las"_ to _C:\Users\Mapoteca2\Desktop\demo\demo.las_ (without " " and with '\' instead of '/')?

Comment: See if it helps: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/lastools/t6Jo0sA9w58

Comment: It seems that Iwas working with an older version of lastools, as pointed by Andre Silva. Now I have both versions working fine